# How to print Current Time and Date

Tags: c, macros

I am confused....I printed `__TIME__` in C then it prints time and then again after 5 seconds I executed it. I did it for 5 times. But for all the times, the time remained same. Time is not getting changed even not second also getting changed. All the time hours minutes and seconds remain same. So how can I print Current Time and Date using time.h

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: `__TIME__` is a preprocessor macro that expands to the time at which the file was compiled. It will not change between consecutive runs of the program.

Comment: Yeah, it's just like `__LINE__` etc, are predefined macros.

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
 clrscr();
 puts(__TIME__);
}

Comment: You need to recompile and run, not just re-run the program.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar That's an answer and worth posting as an answer.

Comment: I am making a program that prints time each time I login & I can not re-compile it  at the time when user is using it

Comment: Is there any solution?

Comment: @KeyurShah : yes - use functions from `time.h`.

Comment: Does the __TIME__ contain the current time when the expansion occurs or the current time at the start of compilation? i.e. would it be possible to have two expansions that contain different values if the compilation crosses the second barrier?

Comment: @EdHeal: That's not clear. It's "the time of translation of the preprocessing translation unit". If that takes more than a second, I suppose it's ambiguous.

Comment: If you want to print the time at which the program runs, you should ask that. Your current question just asks why `__TIME__` works the way it does. Don't just ask why your code behaves the way it does; ask how to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`__TIME__` is a preprocessor macro that expands to the time [at which the file was compiled](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html). It will not change between consecutive runs of the program. As you can see in the link to the documentation that I posted, it clearly says that it expands to a "string constant".

If you want to get the current time, have a look at the `time.h` header.

Comment: Thank You For Answer Daniel Kamil Kozar  I will try it

Comment: To be more accurate: `__TIME__` gets expanded during *pre-processing* of the source file, that it even **before** *compilation*.

Comment: @alk: Preprocessing is part of compilation.

Answer (score 3):

> **`__TIME__`**
>       The time of translation of the preprocessing translation unit: a character
>   string literal of the form **`"hh:mm:ss"`** as in the time generated by the
>   **`asctime`** function. If the time of translation is not available, an
>   implementation-defined valid time shall be supplied.

The important point to note is that it is **indeed** a macro and the substitution happens **during the preprocessing** once for all.

So it won't change even if you print it a **thousand** times

Comment: The macro expansion happens at *preprocessing* time, not during compilation phase.

Comment: @fluter: Preprocessing is part of compilation. The original answer was correct. (I'll update it to quote the definition from the ISO C Standard.)